# Is it possible for an ordinary human male to have sex with a super woman, who has super strength and super durability, without dying?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, super-powers, sex

I recently read an article that said Superman's powers would kill women he had sex with because of his super strength and durability. Would this change if the sexes were reversed ? If not can, anything be done to fix this?

Comment: Could you explain how super "durability" would cause problems in these circumstances?

Comment: No, the praying mantis *will* bite your head off if she feels like it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to worldbuilding.

Comment: Bryan, just what were you ... I mean ... how ... why?

Comment: "Remember kids: when gettin' it on with Superman, always use trusted Kryptonite protection. It's Science Approved!"

Comment: Isn't there a movie somewhat along these lines?  Yes, here it is: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465624/

Comment: On the other hand, if it is not world-building, what exactly is this question ? And while it should be possible, increasing strength levels *are* an problem for spontaneous responses. Animal trainers working with big cats sustained massive injuries or were killed by single strikes which were only intended as warning, gaming or reproach. Roy Horn of Siegfried & Roy got a seizure during a show and Montecore, the white tiger, tried to bring him to safety (which unfortunately for tigers is biting carefully in the neck and dragging to safety).

Answer (score 7):

### Superman's powers probably wouldn't cause problems in the first place

The fact that Superman has super strength does not mean that Superman is always using super strength. Sure, he might have to be careful if he is able to cause harm, but there is no reason why he couldn't be careful, gentle, or slow, to avoid causing harm altogether.

Additionally, Superman does not have to be actively contributing to sexual activity for it to take place. If he is somehow not able to be gentle or graceful, then he can sit still for his partner's safety, and they can do the work.

### This works the other way around

There is no reason why this wouldn't work if the roles were reversed. A Super woman would only have to be gentle or careful to avoid bodily harm.
And again, if somehow she could not be graceful, she could sit still, and her partner could do the work.

Comment: Yay! Quite right! if Superman's superstrength was on permanently he couldn't disguise himself as Clark Kent. Otherwise he would be walking around in a world that was with respective to his titanic strength as fragile as a soap bubble. Larry Niven's article "Man of Steel, Woman of Kleenex" neglected to factor in whatever mechanism(s) gave Superman his super-powers. It simply assumed his superstrength was in play all the time. Plus one from this longtime campaigner against the vile slur on Superman's virility.